# Passing image for tesseract OCR for known bounding box coordinates

Tags: python, image, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I have few images in one folder and have their bounding box coordinates as a txt file for every image as:

0 0.503 0.503 0.334 0.994
(class,x,y,w,h)

My issue is I want to extract text using tesseract OCR using this bounding box on the image.
I have some trouble in the coding part.
Any help  would be appreciated.

(There are basically 2 files in my folder where one has all the images and another one has the bounding box coordinates in a txt file for each image respectively.)
THis is the code below.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
config = ('-l eng --oem 3 --psm 3')
image_path='D:\\Object detection\\test images\\'
labels_path='D:\\Object detection\\labels\\'
for images in os.listdir(image_path):
    spl=images.split('.')[0]
    img_name =os.path.join(image_path,images)
    image=cv2.imread(img_name)
    print(image.shape)
    with open(os.path.join(labels_path,spl+'.txt')) as f:
        t = f.read()
        arr=t.split()
        x,y,w,h=arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[4]
        x=int(x*image.shape[0])
        y=int(y*image.shape[1])
        w=int(w*image.shape[0])
        h=int(h*image.shape[1])
        x1 = round(x-w/2)
        y1 = round(y-h/2)
        x2 = round(x+w/2)
        y2 = round(y+h/2) 
        rect=cv2.rectangle(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,200),3)
        cropped_img = image[y1:y2, x1:x2]
        data = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_img, lang='eng',config=config)
    print(data)
```

There are 2 files with images and their bounding box coordinates as the form given above.
What i want is to loop over both the file where the image name and the label name is same and want to extract text over the ROI. I am getting this error.

```
13         arr=t.split()
     14         x,y,w,h=arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[4]
---> 15         x=int(x*image.shape[0])
     16         y=int(y*image.shape[1])
     17         w=int(w*image.shape[0])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.5030.50
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Split will return an array of strings starting with index 0. Multiplying a string with an integer results into repetition of the string. Try int() directly on x before you multiply with the shape’s dimension.